# UWP InkCanvas fill freehand drawn shape with color

Tags: c#, uwp, inkcanvas

I'm currently working on a UWP app which should allow the user to draw any shape he wants on a InkCanvas. This shapes edges are automatically completed so that there is no open space (Up to this point everything works just fine).

Now my question is: How do I automatically fill this shape with a single color (or a pattern)? I know that there is a "Point in Polygon" algorithm, but I have no idea how to implement it in the UWP InkCanvas, because I don't really get how to search for the points inside the shape without iterating over every point on the canvas.

Edit:
I actually got it done by using a "Canvas" as a overlay to draw a Polyline. By using the Polyline.Fill() method it worked. But I need the same effect on the "InkCanvas" only.

Answer (score 0):

> Now my question is: How do I automatically fill this shape with a single color (or a pattern)? I know that there is a "Point in Polygon" algorithm, but I have no idea how to implement it in the UWP InkCanvas

You could redraw your Ink Strokes that exist in Ink Canvas by setting new `InkDrawingAttributes` for [`InkStroke.DrawingAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Input.Inking.InkStroke#Windows_UI_Input_Inking_InkStroke_DrawingAttributes).

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    InkDrawingAttributes attr = new InkDrawingAttributes();
    attr.Color = Colors.Red;
    attr.IgnorePressure = true;
    attr.PenTip = PenTipShape.Circle;
    attr.Size = new Size(4, 10);
    attr.PenTipTransform = Matrix3x2.CreateRotation((float)(70 * Math.PI / 180));
    IReadOnlyList<InkStroke> InkStrokeList = MyInk.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes();
    foreach (InkStroke temp in InkStrokeList)
    {
        temp.DrawingAttributes = attr; 
    }          
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe I didn't specify my question enough, but I do not want to recolor my ink strokes. I want to fill the drawn "shape" with color. For example on your demo after you click your button the whole thing should be a black "potato shaped" circle.